# Yielding from a PHP method

Tags: oop, generator, yield, php-7.3

I am trying to use `yield` in PHP 7.3, from a class method:

```
<?php

class X {
    public $x;
    public function __construct($x) {
        $this->x = $x;
    }

    public function call_direct() {
        return $this->x;
    }

    public function call_yield() {
        return function() {
            yield $this->x;
        };
    }
}

$a = new X(42);
echo "direct: " . $a->call_direct(), "\n";

$iter = $a->call_yield();
foreach ($iter as $n) {
    echo "yielded: $n\n";
}
```

Naturally, this outputs `direct: 42`... but not the second line. What am I missing to get it to output `yielded: 42` as well? Is this actually possible in PHP these days?

(Obviously my actual example iterates over a list, but I have trimmed it down to the essential).

Comment: You have a superfluous anonymous function wrapper. If you drop the "return function() {}" part, you should get the behavior you expect.

Comment: As I explained, it is not about returning $x. You have just reimplemented `call_direct()`. Imagine it is yielding range(1, 10).